# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I cannot convince why I've encountered following error even I've added following code in NodeJS/ExpressJS.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/polymer/105724/apply.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to allow `OPTIONS` method. Browser sends an `OPTIONS` call before the actual call so if `OPTIONS` is not allowed next call will not be made.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

Answer (score 1):

Allow OPTIONS and reply handling CORS HTTP headers to browser and await the request.