# Still having "No 'Access Control Allow Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error after adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, api, cors

I know this was tackled so many times before. But I can see on the response that there is Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the header already.

This is my request code:

```js
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: "integration-api.domain.com/login",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-AN-WebService-IdentityKey': identitykey,
    'X-AN-WebService-CustomerAuthToken': customerAuth,
    'X-AN-WebService-CustomerTransientToken': transientToken,
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  },
  data: datatopass
};

console.log(datatopass);

return $http(req).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
  return response.data;
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return err;
});
```

**This is the request header when viewing on chrome:**

> **Accept**:*/*
>   **Accept-Encoding**:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>   **Accept-Language**:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   **Access-Control-Request-Headers**:x-an-webservice-identitykey
>   **Access-Control-Request-Method**:POST
>   **Cache-Control**:no-cache
>   **Connection**:keep-alive
>   **Host**:integration-api.domain.com
>   **Origin**:http://OriginDomain
>   **Pragma**:no-cache
>   **Referer**:http://OriginDomain/apitest/
>   **User-Agent**:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36

**Then the preflight response is:**

> **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**:x-an-webservice-identitykey, origin, content-type, x-an-webservice-customerauthtoken, x-an-webservice-deviceauthtoken,x-an-webservice-customertransienttoken,x-an-webservice-version
>   **Access-Control-Allow-Origin**:*
>   Date:Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:56:50 GMT

Does the server needs to add Access-Control-Allow-Method or any other headers on the response or do I need to add something on my code?

I'm using angular.js to call an $http call to the url

Comment: how do you resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow method types as well

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*";
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE";
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type";
```

Please see this answer.
[Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758013/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check-in-nodejs/40758058#40758058)

Comment: Thank you very much! So the server side team needs to add these CORS option as well?

Comment: Yes if api is to be called from different domain.

Comment: I've the allowed methods, still same issue